# how to configure virtual switch to connect to internet

Tags: networking

I have a network as shown in the picture.  The problem that I'm having is that I want those two virtual machines to have access to the internet without using a hyperV External switch.

Is there any way that the virtual NIC on the host machine can get internet from a WIFI interface without sharing it? I want it to be like a routing system on Windows server.

Network setup:

[image]

Comment: network adapter > select both> create virtual bridge?

Comment: that would be the same as Hyper-V external Switch. what I`m trying to do is, having access to internet through my virtual machines without using Virtual bridges or sharing the WiFi connection. the reason is , in this case windows does not recognize my connection as WiFi any more. is it possible to do it with route command?

Comment: I've not tried that

Comment: is it possible that you try it?